# Swift Init does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'

Tags: swift, decodable

At the moment, I have a struct that conforms to Codable:

```
public struct Preference: Codable {

    public let id: String

}
```

When I try to initialize the object using the following:

```
let preference = Preference(id: "cool")
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'
```

How can I fix this issue and initialize the struct properly?

Comment: Strange, that compiles without problems in my Xcode 9.2.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this. I suspect this is not the actual code. What line does this error appear on? Is `Preference` have exactly this one property in your code?

Comment: Start a new project and try to construct a [mcve].

Comment: @RobNapier This is actual code and the error occurs when trying to initialize the object.

Comment: Perhaps you autocompleted to `let preference = Preference(from: "cool")` ? That would give you that error. Maybe you forgot to change it to the correct initializer or changed it and the compiler is slow in catching up? Maybe try a clean?

Comment: @ekreloff if you use the "from:" initializer you've got to then force cast the string to conform to decoder.

Comment: This compiles and runs correctly. Must be something else in your codebase? Xcode version?

Comment: @AdamCooper, I'm just suggesting the circumstance when that error would appear.

Comment: So apparently the type is defined in a framework (module), and the constructor called from outside of the module? – That would be an important information to add to the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When struct is created without *explicit* initializer

```
public struct Preference {
    public let id: String
}
```

it gets `internal init(id: String)` initializer for free. Internal means that using it from another target will result in compiler error.

Adding `Decodable` to your struct also adds `public init(from: Decoder)` initializer to this struct.

So initial struct is equivalent to the following

```
public struct Preference: Codable {
    public let id: String

    internal init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }

    public init(from: Decoder) {
        // generated decoding code
    }
}
```

When you try to create an instance using `Preference(id: "cool")` from another target there is only one public initializer: the one with the decoder. Compiler tries to use it by casting `String` to `Decoder` and it fails.

To resolve the original issue you need to add `public init(id: String)` initializer explicitly.